# Page Curl download link missing

Tags: android

Im having dificulty finding the download link given here in stockoverflow about android page curl. Just like the iphone animation between activities. They gave me this link: http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/ but i cant find the download link. Is this a deadlink? And Im somehow confused in these two link :

http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/

https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/

Are they the same?

Comment: Ever worked with git? If not on Github there are 2 Buttons "Clone in Windows" and "Zip", which means download as zip (mouse over text).

Comment: hehe.. i know git but i dont use it.. its hard to set it up in eclipse..

Comment: Here is the link to download this sample, https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/zipball/master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download source code use [This Link](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html) to download TortoiseSVN and install it.

Now create a folder anywhere in your PC then right click on it, Click on SVN Checkout option and paste `http://android-page-curl.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/`for http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/ this

and `https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl.git` for https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/ this

in URL field and click OK. Your code will be downloaded in your folder.

Answer (score 0):

The source can be downloaded using subversion as described [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/source/checkout):

*Command-line access
Use this command to anonymously check out the latest project source code:*

```
# Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP.
svn checkout http://android-page-curl.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ android-page-curl-read-only
```

Comment: If he do not know how to get such a project, he would not have git or svn installed :)

Comment: Oh i see.. Thank you.. Ahm but do i have to manuly get all this? in here? http://android-page-curl.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ ?

Comment: @Fabian Ahm yeah i dont git.. hehehe ^_^

Comment: @nelzkie: Yeap. Get the trunk directory and that should be the latest code.  Have fun!